# need SQL query to replace foreign language characters from string

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

CodeIgniter does not allow foreign language characters in the URL
The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.

> [http://allvideolectures.com/v/R4717Cf87j/QM41-Potential-Barrier-E-â-V-The-scattering-problem](http://allvideolectures.com/v/R4717Cf87j/QM41-Potential-Barrier-E-%C3%A2-V-The-scattering-problem)

i have created ID as **QM41-Potential-Barrier-E-â-V-The-scattering-problem**
some of them contain **foreign characters** that needs to be replaced with normal character

i tried to solve the problem with the php strtr() function but failed to get proper result as List is very long 
i need a Direct SQL solution if there is any

Answer (score 0):

Transliterates high ASCII characters to low ASCII equivalents, useful when non-English characters need to be used where only standard ASCII characters are safely used, for instance, in URLs.try,

```
$string = convert_accented_characters($string);
```